# How to add jqgrid data in database all at once via an external button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

How can I do to add value in jqgrid and save it later in the database via an external button that I created in my page out of jqgrid?

I have the following jqgrid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...

    jQuery(#grid-table).jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetStore", "Store")',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        height: '430',
        colNames: [ 'Code', 'Name' ],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', sorttype: "int" },
            { key: false, name: 'Name', index: 'Name', editable: true }
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 15],
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false
            Id: "0"
        },
        pager: jQuery(#grid-pager),
        altRows: true,
        multiselect: true,
        multiboxonly: true,
        caption: "Stores",
    });

    jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('navGrid', #grid-pager,
        {   //navbar options
            edit: false,
            add: true,
            del: false,
            search: false,
            refresh: false,
            view: false,
        },
        {
            recreateForm: true,
            url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Store")',
        },
        {
            recreateForm: true,
            url: '@Url.Action("Create","Store")',
        },
        {
            recreateForm: true,
            url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Store")',
        },
        {
            recreateForm: true,
            multipleSearch: true
        },
        {
            recreateForm: true,
        }
    )
</script>

....

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="subitbutton"> 
    Create 
</button>
```

And the following code in my Model:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }
```

And the following code in my Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetStores(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, int idStore) 
{
    int pageIndex = page - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    var storesResults = db.Stores.Select(
            a => new { a.Id, a.Name });

    int totalRecords = storesResults.Count();
    var totalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling((float) totalRecords / (float) rows);
    if (sord.ToUpper() == "ASC")
    {
        storesResults = storesResults.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
        storesResults = storesResults.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }
    else
    {
        storesResults = storesResults.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
        storesResults = storesResults.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }
    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = totalPages, page, records = totalRecords, rows = storesResults
    };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Stores store)
{
    db.Store.Add(store);
    return view(store);
}

public ActionResult Edit(Store store)
{
    if (ModelState.isValid)
    {
        db.Entry(store).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View(store);
}

public void Delete(string id)
{
    var ids = id.Split(',');
    foreach (var idStore in ids)
    {
        int storeId = Convert.ToInt32(idStore);
        Store storeToDelete = db.Stores.Find(storeId);
        db.Stores.Remove(storeToDelete);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Right now, my jqgrid sends each new row to the server and my method saves it in the database.
What I need is to store all rows in my view and send all at once in a single step to my server - using an external button, maybe?

Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE***

As requested by Oleg, here is my jqGrid demo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var grid_selector = "#grid-table-dados-adicionais";
        var pager_selector = "#grid-pager-dados-adicionais";

        //resize to fit page size
        $(window).on('resize.jqGrid', function () {
            $(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridWidth', $(".page-content").width());
        })
        //resize on sidebar collapse/expand
        var parent_column = $(grid_selector).closest('[class*="col-"]');
        $(document).on('settings.ace.jqGrid', function (ev, event_name, collapsed) {
            if (event_name === 'sidebar_collapsed' || event_name === 'main_container_fixed') {
                //setTimeout is for webkit only to give time for DOM changes and then redraw!!!
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridWidth', parent_column.width());
                }, 0);
            }
        })

        jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
            //direction: "rtl",

            url: '@Url.Action("GetDadosAdicionais", "LojaDadosAdicionais", new { idLoja = @Model.Id })',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'Get',
            height: '430',
            colNames: [' ',
                       'Id',
                       'Name'
            ],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'myac', index: '', width: 65, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false,
                    formatter: 'actions',
                    formatoptions: {
                        keys: true,
                        delOptions: {
                            recreateForm: true,
                            reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                            beforeShowForm: beforeDeleteCallback
                        },
                        editformbutton: true,
                        editOptions:
                        {
                            recreateForm: true,
                            reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                            closeAfterEdit: true,
                            beforeShowForm: beforeEditCallback,
                            closeOnEscape: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', sorttype: "int", editable: false },
                { key: false, hidden: true, name: 'Name', index: 'Name', sorttype: "int", editable: true },
            ],

            viewrecords: true,
            loadonce: true,
            editurl: "clientArray",
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 15],
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                Id: "0"
            },
            pager: jQuery(pager_selector),
            altRows: true,
            //toppager: true,
            autowidth: true,
            multiselect: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            scrollOffset: 0,
            height: "auto",
            //multikey: "ctrlKey",
            multiboxonly: true,
            loadComplete: function () {
                var table = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    updateActionIcons(table);
                    updatePagerIcons(table);
                    enableTooltips(table);
                }, 0);
            },
            caption: "Registration",
        });
        $(window).triggerHandler('resize.jqGrid');//trigger window resize to make the grid get the correct size

        //switch element when editing inline
        function aceSwitch(cellvalue, options, cell) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(cell).find('input[type=checkbox]')
                    .addClass('ace ace-switch ace-switch-5')
                    .after('<span class="lbl"></span>');
            }, 0);
        }

        //navButtons
        jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('navGrid', pager_selector,
            {   //navbar options
                edit: true,
                editicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-pencil blue',
                add: true,
                addicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-plus-circle purple',
                del: true,
                delicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-trash-o red',
                search: true,
                searchicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search orange',
                refresh: true,
                refreshicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-refresh green',
                view: true,
                viewicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search-plus grey',
            },
            {
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                width: 500,
                beforeShowForm: function (e) {
                    var form = $(e[0]);
                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').find('.ui-jqdialog-titlebar').wrapInner('<div class="widget-header" />')
                    style_edit_form(form);
                }
            },
            {
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                width: 500,
                beforeShowForm: function (e) {
                    var form = $(e[0]);
                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').find('.ui-jqdialog-titlebar')
                    .wrapInner('<div class="widget-header" />')
                    style_edit_form(form);
                }
            },
            {
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterDelete: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                beforeShowForm: function (e) {
                    var form = $(e[0]);
                    if (form.data('styled')) return false;
                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').find('.ui-jqdialog-titlebar').wrapInner('<div class="widget-header" />')
                    style_delete_form(form);
                    form.data('styled', true);
                }
            },
            {
                //search form
                recreateForm: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                afterShowSearch: function (e) {
                    var form = $(e[0]);
                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').find('.ui-jqdialog-title').wrap('<div class="widget-header" />')
                    style_search_form(form);
                },
                afterRedraw: function () {
                    style_search_filters($(this));
                },
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterSearch: true,
                multipleSearch: true
            },
            {
                //view record form
                recreateForm: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                beforeShowForm: function (e) {
                    var form = $(e[0]);
                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').find('.ui-jqdialog-title').wrap('<div class="widget-header" />')
                }
            }
        )

        $.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
            beforeSubmit: function () {
                $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" });
                return [true, "", ""];
            }
        });


        $.extend($.jgrid.add, {
            beforeSubmit: function () {
                $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" });
                return [true, "", ""];
            }
        });

        $('#filterButton').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            filterGrid();
        });

        $('#TargetDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
        });

        function filterGrid() {
            var postDataValues = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');

            // grab all the filter ids and values and add to the post object
            $('.filterItem').each(function (index, item) {
                postDataValues[$(item).attr('id')] = $(item).val();
            });

            $('#grid').jqGrid().setGridParam({ postData: postDataValues, page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
        }

        function style_edit_form(form) {
            //enable datepicker on "sdate" field and switches for "stock" field
            form.find('input[name=sdate]').datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', autoclose: true })

            form.find('input[name=stock]').addClass('ace ace-switch ace-switch-5').after('<span class="lbl"></span>');

            //update buttons classes
            var buttons = form.next().find('.EditButton .fm-button');
            buttons.addClass('btn btn-sm').find('[class*="-icon"]').hide();//ui-icon, s-icon
            buttons.eq(0).addClass('btn-primary').prepend('<i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"></i>');
            buttons.eq(1).prepend('<i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i>')

            buttons = form.next().find('.navButton a');
            buttons.find('.ui-icon').hide();
            buttons.eq(0).append('<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-left"></i>');
            buttons.eq(1).append('<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
        }

        function style_delete_form(form) {
            var buttons = form.next().find('.EditButton .fm-button');
            buttons.addClass('btn btn-sm btn-white btn-round').find('[class*="-icon"]').hide();//ui-icon, s-icon
            buttons.eq(0).addClass('btn-danger').prepend('<i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o"></i>');
            buttons.eq(1).addClass('btn-default').prepend('<i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i>')
        }

        function style_search_filters(form) {
            form.find('.delete-rule').val('X');
            form.find('.add-rule').addClass('btn btn-xs btn-primary');
            form.find('.add-group').addClass('btn btn-xs btn-success');
            form.find('.delete-group').addClass('btn btn-xs btn-danger');
        }
        function style_search_form(form) {
            var dialog = form.closest('.ui-jqdialog');
            var buttons = dialog.find('.EditTable')
            buttons.find('.EditButton a[id*="_reset"]').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-info').find('.ui-icon').attr('class', 'ace-icon fa fa-retweet');
            buttons.find('.EditButton a[id*="_query"]').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-inverse').find('.ui-icon').attr('class', 'ace-icon fa fa-comment-o');
            buttons.find('.EditButton a[id*="_search"]').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-purple').find('.ui-icon').attr('class', 'ace-icon fa fa-search');
        }

        function beforeDeleteCallback(e) {
            var form = $(e[0]);
            if (form.data('styled')) return false;

            form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').find('.ui-jqdialog-titlebar').wrapInner('<div class="widget-header" />')
            style_delete_form(form);

            form.data('styled', true);
        }

        function beforeEditCallback(e) {
            var form = $(e[0]);
            form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').find('.ui-jqdialog-titlebar').wrapInner('<div class="widget-header" />')
            style_edit_form(form);
        }

        //replace icons with FontAwesome icons like above
        function updatePagerIcons(table) {
            var replacement =
            {
                'ui-icon-seek-first': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left bigger-140',
                'ui-icon-seek-prev': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-left bigger-140',
                'ui-icon-seek-next': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-right bigger-140',
                'ui-icon-seek-end': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right bigger-140'
            };
            $('.ui-pg-table:not(.navtable) > tbody > tr > .ui-pg-button > .ui-icon').each(function () {
                var icon = $(this);
                var $class = $.trim(icon.attr('class').replace('ui-icon', ''));

                if ($class in replacement) icon.attr('class', 'ui-icon ' + replacement[$class]);
            })
        }

        function updateActionIcons(table) {
            var replacement =
            {
                'ui-ace-icon fa fa-pencil': 'ace-icon fa fa-pencil blue',
                'ui-ace-icon fa fa-trash-o': 'ace-icon fa fa-trash-o red',
                'ui-icon-disk': 'ace-icon fa fa-check green',
                'ui-icon-cancel': 'ace-icon fa fa-times red'
            };
            $(table).find('.ui-pg-div span.ui-icon').each(function () {
                var icon = $(this);
                var $class = $.trim(icon.attr('class').replace('ui-icon', ''));
                if ($class in replacement) icon.attr('class', 'ui-icon ' + replacement[$class]);
            })
        }

        function enableTooltips(table) {
            $('.navtable .ui-pg-button').tooltip({ container: 'body' });
            $(table).find('.ui-pg-div').tooltip({ container: 'body' });
        }

        //var selr = jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');

        $(document).one('ajaxloadstart.page', function (e) {
            $(grid_selector).jqGrid('GridUnload');
            $('.ui-jqdialog').remove();
        });

    });
</script>

....

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="submitbutton"> 
    Create 
</button>
```

Comment: The server code seems be not oriented on the usage of `loadonce: true` option. It should return **all data** instead of only one requested page. You should just return all data without any call of `.Count`, `.Skip` and `.Take`. The returned data could be just array of items. No `total`, `page` or `records` are required. The wrapping results in `rows` property is also not needed `return Json(db.Stores.Select(a => new { a.Id, a.Name }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` will be already enough.

Comment: @Oleg, thank you for your suggestion.I will change my code to include this. But what I'm not able is to create a way to get the various rows that have been created in the grid and send them to the database only when to click on button that was created out of my jqgrid. I added the code snippet of my button in the above example. I would like that somehow these added data stay on the screen and only went to the database when this external button is clicked. In my code, the method that is responsible for saving data in the database is the "Create". Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? I suppose you want to use **local editing**, but you want to use form editing. To get the data from the grid you can use `$("#grid-table").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand you then you can use `editurl: "clientArray"` to make **local** editing. You use form editing. So you should use jqGrid 4.7 or better [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (or the latest version from github).

```
$("#subitbutton").click(function () {
    var localGridData = $("#grid-table").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
    $.ajax({
        url: "someServerMethod",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(localGridData),
        dataType: "json"
    })
});
```

Depend on the implementation on the server side the format of the value of the `data` parameter can be different. You can probably use `data: { gridData: localGridData }` or some another option of jQuery.ajax.